# I want to allow the user to input in a textfield 1' 2-3/4" in my iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios

can anyone point me in the direction of any tutorials on how to analyze the value a user inputs. I have googled this numerous ways and not seeming to find anything i can follow.

The purpose of this app is a calculator. currently the user can enter an integer/decimal for representing inches and fractions. i want them to be able to insert feet inches and fractions. is there a way to analyze the value before the ' to know that is feet and then analyze the integer before the " as inches. not sure how to evaluate X" vs X-y/z" where as maybe if - is present then next value is numerator and after the / is denominator. If anyone can suggest any resources for something like this it would be of great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I think you are either going to have to build a custom keyboard from scratch with the symbols you need ( ' " / etc) to or add an additional keyboard bar that contains the additional symbols you need.  This will feed the symbols into a UITextField.

Once the user can tap your keyboard to enter things like `1' 2/3"`, you will need to intercept the `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method of the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol and manually validate the inserted numbers and symbols to suit your format.  This is where the magic will start to happen.

As to what magic to write.  You need to decide what is a valid pattern and apply some simple rules.  I'd suggest that a regular expression would be a good way to go. In terms of your problem domain check out [Regular Expression for Feet, Inches and Fractions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/170d98da-a282-4776-b317-49fe5144f81a/regex-for-feet-and-fractional-inches) (Which I picked out of the internet at random after googling for `regular expression for feet and inches`)

If `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` validates the new user input as a genuine feet and inches, it simply returns true and the user keypress is allowed.  Now you know you have a valid pattern in the text field.  from here you need to write a parser of some sort that walks over the text and extracts the numerical value.  I can't find anything that would directly solve your problem, but I would look at writing a state machine that started at the left most character and then walked left to write, building up the components of numerical feet and inches.

As for me .. I was thinking about something similar and took the easy way out .. decimal inches :D

Comment: Ooh... custom keyboard, I like that idea. But all the classical string validation issues still apply (as we both mention) in order to, e.g., support copy/paste.

Comment: With copy/paste you intercept the <UITextFieldDelegate> textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:  and validate that the resultant string still fits your pattern

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just mentioning that so that the OP doesn't think that a custom keyboard handles every issue. (I would maintain that putting the validation in a formatter leads to a cleaner architecture, though.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an entirely trivial problem (and illustrates one of the many reasons that SI/metric should be adopted universally).

To do the actual parsing you have a couple options. You could use NSScanner to read the string left to right and interpret it as you go.  But the task seems particularly well suited to regular expressions since it is a highly constrained syntax. The class you will want to examine is NSRegularExpression. A simple regex you could start with could be something like (untested):

```
(\d*)'?\s+((\d+)-)?((\d+)")?
```

(Clearly you would need to tune this seat-of-the-pants expression quite a bit.  And if you're unfamiliar with regexes then you will have a bit of a learning curve. I recommend O'Reilly's "Mastering Regular Expressions".)

Once you have figured out your parsing/validation algorithm, wrap it up inside a custom NSFormatter (or NSNumberFormatter). See the Data Formatting Programming Guide for tutorials. (Note that you will likely need to creat a helper model class to hold fractions that the formatted will communicate with.)